# Arranging the references in the alphabetical order of the surname of the first author

Tags: bibtex, citing, springernature

I am using Springer Nature Latex template. Which document class and bibliography style should be used to arrange the references in the alphabetical order of the surname of the first author? Also the references should be listed in numbers.

Eg :
[1] Broy, M.. Software engineering—from auxiliary to key technologies.
M. Broy & E. Denert (Eds.), Software pioneers (pp. 10–13). New York:
Springer (1992).
[2] Campbell, S.L., & Gear, C.W. . The index of general nonlinear DAES.
Numer. Math., 72 (2), 173–196 (1995).

Comment: Are you sure, that it should be sorted this way? The example file of [the sprinter nature template](https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support), just uses `\bibliography{sn-bibliography}` and results in another order.